# Как 2-ум и более одинаковым классам дать eventlistener?

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть 2 кнопки с классом `.bg-grey`. Нужно, чтобы они выполняли одинаковую функцию, при нажатии на них. Я буквально неделю изучаю JS, поэтому ума не приложу как это сделать. Прошу объяснить, как это делать и как это работает

Мой вариант таков(не работает):

```
let BtnBgGrey = document.querySelectorAll('.bg-grey');

BtnBgGrey.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log ('click')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.bg-grey').forEach(b => 
  b.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log ('click')
  })
);
```